# jQuery number increment/decrement by pixel movement, using mouseenter and mousemove

Tags: jquery, increment, mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have this jQuery.
The code gets the coordinates where the mouse enters, offset to start at 0:

```
var inc_X_by = 0, inc_Y_by = 0, total_X = 0, total_Y = 0;

$( "#mouse_over" ).mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      offset = $this.offset(),
      in_X = (event.clientX - offset.left),
      in_Y = (event.clientY - offset.top);
```

then gets the coordinates as the mouse moves inside:

```
  $('#mouse_over').mousemove(function(e){
    var mouse_X = (event.clientX - offset.left),
        mouse_Y = (event.clientY - offset.top);
```

and gives a total increment + or - the difference:

```
    inc_X_by =  mouse_X - in_X;
    inc_Y_by =  mouse_Y - in_Y;    
  });
```

Then when the mouse leaves the div it adds the increment/decrement to a total each time:

```
}).mouseleave(function() {
  total_X = total_X + inc_X_by;
  total_Y = total_Y + inc_Y_by;
});
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nathansonic/2fwb94wL/1/)

At the moment the total of all increments only updates when the mouse leaves the div. However I want it to update *continuously* as the mouse moves inside. If I drop the totals calculations into the mousemove function it adds the inc number EVERY single time it changes, ie: if the inc goes up by two pixels, from 100 to 102, instead of adding 2 it adds 100, 101, 102 = 303. A big difference.

Anyone know a solution?

As a noob any other advice on the code is greatly appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a new var:

```
var X_prev = 0, Y_prev = 0;
```

and then an if/else statement that determines if the mouse is moving l/r, h/v

```
if (X_prev < mouse_X) { 
    inc_X_by = 1;
  } else if (X_prev == mouse_X) {
    inc_X_by = 0;
  } else {
    inc_X_by = -1;
  };
```

then set prev mouse position to current.

```
X_prev = mouse_X;
```

so if, for example, previous mouse position is less than current, then mouse is moving right, set increment to +1. Then by moving the totals into mousemove, it adds +1 each time it fires. Then there's no need for mouseenter or mouseleave.

The complete code looks like this, [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nathansonic/2fwb94wL/3/):

```
var inc_X_by = 0, inc_Y_by = 0, total_X = 0, total_Y = 0, X_prev = 0, Y_prev = 0;

$('#mouse_over').mousemove(function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        offset = $this.offset(),
        mouse_X = (event.clientX - offset.left),
        mouse_Y = (event.clientY - offset.top);

      if (X_prev < mouse_X) { 
          inc_X_by = 1;
      } else if (X_prev == mouse_X) {
          inc_X_by = 0;
      } else {
          inc_X_by = -1;
      };

      if (Y_prev < mouse_Y) { 
          inc_Y_by = 1;
      } else if (Y_prev == mouse_Y) {
          inc_Y_by = 0;
      } else {
          inc_Y_by = -1;
      }

      X_prev = mouse_X;
      Y_prev = mouse_Y;

      total_X = total_X + inc_X_by;
      total_Y = total_Y + inc_Y_by;
    });
})
```

One major difference is that if the mouse skips over very quickly then mousemove only fires a couple of times, therefore you will only increment by a few, when in fact you may have travelled much more.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your mousemove code to mouseenter function , Its work in your jsfiddle with these changes.

Just change your jquery code with following :-

```
var inc_X_by = 0, inc_Y_by = 0, total_X = 0, total_Y = 0;

$( "#mouse_over" ).mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      offset = $this.offset(),
      in_X = (event.clientX - offset.left),
      in_Y = (event.clientY - offset.top);

  $('#coords_in').html("mouseenter coords = " + in_X + ", " + in_Y);

  $('#mouse_over').mousemove(function(e){
    var mouse_X = (event.clientX - offset.left),
        mouse_Y = (event.clientY - offset.top);

    $('#coords').html("mousemove coords = " + mouse_X + ', ' + mouse_Y);

    inc_X_by =  mouse_X - in_X;
    inc_Y_by =  mouse_Y - in_Y;
    $('#inc_by').html("current increment = " + inc_X_by + ", " + inc_Y_by);

        total_X = total_X + inc_X_by;
  total_Y = total_Y + inc_Y_by;
  $('#total').html("total of all increments = " + total_X + ", " + total_Y);

  });

}).mouseleave(function() {
  total_X = total_X + inc_X_by;
  total_Y = total_Y + inc_Y_by;
  $('#total').html("total of all increments = " + total_X + ", " + total_Y);
});
```

It may help you.

Comment: Hi. It looks like it works, but it doesn't. It's something I already tried, as mentioned in the q.
It's adding the whole 'inc_X_by' EVERY time it changes, resulting in massive numbers, ie: if the inc goes up by two pixels, from 100 to 102, instead of adding 2 it adds 100, 101, 102 = 303. A big difference.